# How to correctly set up multiple product offer schema per page

Tags: seo, json-ld

For some reason I am having great difficulty finding this out. I have had a look here:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product

And here:

https://schema.org/Product

But none of the examples given show me how to add multiple product offers on a page. To illustrate what I am talking about, here is an example on our site:

https://reclaimdesign.org/vases-reclaimed-wood-stands.html

I have been having a to and fro with RankMath support about this and they tell me this is not possible. I don't believe they are right in saying that but I cannot find 100% irrefutable evidence to illustrate otherwise.

I am currently working to set up the schema myself (as the to and fro is now feeling like a waste of time). My schema code for the above page validates in the Structured Data Testing Tool:

```
`<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "brand": "Reclaim Design",
  "logo": "https://reclaimdesign.org/wp-content/uploads/reclaim-design-logo.jpg",
  "name": "4 Glamorous Sustainable Vases – Home Decor | Reclaim Design",
  "image": [   "https://reclaimdesign.org/wp-content/uploads/1x1/test-tube-vases-sustainable-reclaimed-wood-stand1.jpg",    
"https://reclaimdesign.org/wp-content/uploads/4x3/test-tube-vases-sustainable-reclaimed-wood-stand1.jpg", 
"https://reclaimdesign.org/wp-content/uploads/16x9/test-tube-vases-sustainable-reclaimed-wood-stand1.jpg","https://reclaimdesign.org/wp-content/uploads/1x1/test-tube-vases-sustainable-reclaimed-wood-stand5.jpg",    
"https://reclaimdesign.org/wp-content/uploads/4x3/test-tube-vases-sustainable-reclaimed-wood-stand5.jpg", 
"https://reclaimdesign.org/wp-content/uploads/16x9/test-tube-vases-sustainable-reclaimed-wood-stand5.jpg","https://reclaimdesign.org/wp-content/uploads/1x1/bottle-vases-sustainable-reclaimed-wood-stand1.jpg",    
"https://reclaimdesign.org/wp-content/uploads/4x3/bottle-vases-sustainable-reclaimed-wood-stand1.jpg", 
"https://reclaimdesign.org/wp-content/uploads/16x9/bottle-vases-sustainable-reclaimed-wood-stand1.jpg","https://reclaimdesign.org/wp-content/uploads/1x1/recycled-gin-bottle-vase-sustainable-reclaimed-wood-stand.jpg",    
"https://reclaimdesign.org/wp-content/uploads/4x3/recycled-gin-bottle-vase-sustainable-reclaimed-wood-stand.jpg", 
"https://reclaimdesign.org/wp-content/uploads/16x9/recycled-gin-bottle-vase-sustainable-reclaimed-wood-stand.jpg"
   ],
  "url": "https://reclaimdesign.org/vases-reclaimed-wood-stands.html",
  "@id": "https://reclaimdesign.org/vases-reclaimed-wood-stands.html",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "https://reclaimdesign.org/search?q={search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  },
  "sameAs":
["https://www.facebook.com/reclaimdesignza",
"https://twitter.com/ReclaimDesignZA",
"https://www.instagram.com/reclaimdesign/",
"https://za.pinterest.com/reclaimdesignza/",
"https://www.google.com/maps/place/Reclaim+Design/@-34.03081,18.4517513,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x1dcc4242e6ad5367:0xcf5844aec51f1a43!8m2!3d-34.03081!4d18.45394"
],
  "description": "Click here to find out more about our sustainable vases and vase sets with reclaimed wood stands | Reclaim Design",
  "offers": [{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "price": "390",
    "priceCurrency": "ZAR",
    "url": "https://reclaimdesign.org/home-decor-shop.html/Test-Tube-Vases-With-Stand-p134947241"
  },{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "price": "290",
    "priceCurrency": "ZAR",
    "url": "https://reclaimdesign.org/home-decor-shop.html/Test-Tube-Vases-With-Stand-p134947241"
  },{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "price": "370",
    "priceCurrency": "ZAR",
    "url": "https://reclaimdesign.org/home-decor-shop.html/Bottle-Vases-with-Stand-p65343612"
  },{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "price": "250",
    "priceCurrency": "ZAR",
    "url": "https://reclaimdesign.org/vases-reclaimed-wood-stands.html"
  },{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "price": "300",
    "priceCurrency": "ZAR",
    "url": "https://reclaimdesign.org/home-decor-shop.html/Floating-Globe-Vase-With-Stand-p65346003"
  }]
}
</script>`
```

The RankMath support tell me "you should not use more than one product Schema per page. It does not make much sense and would only confuse Google." If they are right, why then would the code validate in Google's own testing tool?

Please can somebody with experience in this arena explain which is the correct way of doing this? TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can markup your services as a product.

Two reasons to do this

Google doesn’t support “service” markup
Services are included in Product’s definition in schema.org
If you have multiple different services on a single page, then markup them one by one - individually.

If you have same services but with vivid options and price packages then use aggregate product markup.

Read about Google’s structured data product markup. You will get the sample code, which you can modify as per the requirements.

Comment: Thanks GotTheJob. I came up with a solution that worked by using listitems and setting product types within each of these.... Validates in Google's SDTT and doesn't break the RanKMath breadcrumb, so happy days (for now ;))